# Add onfocus, onblur and onchange on every select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add to every select tag in a page something like:

```
onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'
```

using a js in the head.

I tried:

```
<script>
// onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'

var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i=0; i<sels.length;i++){
    sels[i].onfocus=function() {
        sels[i].setAttribute("size","10"); 
    }
    sels[i].onblur=function() {
        sels[i].setAttribute("size","1"); 
    }
    sels[i].onchange=function() {
        sels[i].setAttribute("size","1");
        sels[i].blur();
    }
}
</script>
```

It doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference current select element with `this`:

```
var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i = 0; i < sels.length; i++) {
    sels[i].onfocus = function () {
        this.setAttribute("size", "10");
    }
    sels[i].onblur = function () {
        this.setAttribute("size", "1");
    }
    sels[i].onchange = function () {
        this.setAttribute("size", "1");
        this.blur();
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zrnw/

Or you could use a immediate functions to store a current index `i` value into the closure. Otherwise by the time of the event `i` is equal to `sels.lenght` and `sels[i]` is undefined.

```
var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i = 0; i < sels.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        sels[i].onfocus=function() {
            sels[i].setAttribute("size","10"); 
        }
        sels[i].onblur=function() {
            sels[i].setAttribute("size","1"); 
        }
        sels[i].onchange=function() {
            sels[i].setAttribute("size","1");
            sels[i].blur();
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all. In my case, it works only if the javascript that you suggested is placed at the end of the page before </body>, but it doesn't work if this js is placed in the top of the page before </head>.

Comment: Of course, DOM needs to be available when you execute the code. you can place it in `window.onload = function() { /* above code */ }` if you want to use it in `head`.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You need to use "this" to refer to the select in focus.

```
<script>

var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i=0; i<sels.length;i++){
    sels[i].onfocus=function() {
        this.setAttribute("size","10"); 
    }
    sels[i].onblur=function() {
       this.setAttribute("size","1"); 
    }
    sels[i].onchange=function() {
        this.setAttribute("size","1");
        this.blur();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner / more efficient method would be to use .each() to iterate and the 'this' keyword for the current iteration

```
$('select').each(function (){
  $(this).onfocus = function () {
    this.setAttribute("size", "10");
  }
  $(this).onblur = function () {
    this.setAttribute("size", "1");
  }
  $(this).onchange = function () {
    this.setAttribute("size", "1");
    this.blur();
  }
});
```